# Object to array to generate API payload

Tags: php, arrays, object

I know that the title might be really similar to other existing questions but the actual problem is really different from the ones existing (at least I can't really find another one similar).

I have an API that I need to communicate with in order to create a customer, in the fields to create a new customer, there's the `Address` field, and yes, the field requires the `A` uppercase. But what this all mean?

I thought about creating entities with public method so I can convert them to array and generate the payload to send, something like this:

```
class Customer extends Entity
{
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $phone;
    public $address;
}
```

This entity would be easily converted to array by just using `(array)` or even using `get_object_vars`, the real problem here is that I want `$address` to be an instance of another entity called `Address`, like this:

```
class Address extends Entity
{
    public $street;
    public $number;
    public $city;
    public $state;
}
```

For this I implemented one method called `properties`, like this:

```
abstract class Entity {
    public function properties(): array
    {
        $convert = function($value) use(&$convert)
        {
            return is_scalar($value) ? $value : array_map($convert, (array) $value);
        };

        return $convert($this);
    }
}
```

It works, it will transform recursively.

The problem here is: instead of `Address` as key, it's returning `address` in lower case (obviously) because it's only getting the fields.

I was wondering, how can I accomplish that? How can I set the key with the first letter uppercase if the field of an entity is an object (another entity)?

The expected result would be something like:

```
[
    'name' => '...'
    'email' => '...'
    'phone' => '...'
    'Address' => [
        'street' => '...'
        'number' => '...'
        'city' => '...'
        'state' => '...'
    ]
]
```

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Why are you over complicating this? Why you don't create the JSON by setting the keys by yourself?

Comment: @ReynierPM because it's easier to fill a class with the fields already there instead of having to manually write every field key and value and having to remember that the `Address` has to have capital A. This is just an example, the API is all like this for other entites, for instance `Card`, `Address`, and so on.

Comment: I didn't mean to build the whole JSON, that is crazy I won't do it if I were you but you can easily build the content of those `values` and then attach that key after the big JSON is created :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reverse the condition, and use the class name as the key if the value of the property is an instance of Entity.

```
public function properties(): array
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($this as $key => $value) {
        if ($value instanceof Entity) {
            $result[get_class($value)] = $value->properties();
        } else {
            $result[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I can see some potential drawbacks to the general idea of this, though. For example, if a person entity needs to have multiple addresses at some point this won't work because the second address will overwrite the first one. You could just strtoupper the property name, but if it isn't the class name, it seems like it wouldn't really matter if it was capitalized or not.